# two-dimensional version of "$F_X(X)$ is uniformly distributed"?

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, uniform-distribution, cumulative-distribution-functions

It is a well-known fact in probability theory that if $X$ is a continuous random variable and $F_X$ is a cdf of $X$, then $F_X(X)$ is uniformly distributed over $[0, 1]$.

Is there a two-dimensional version of this statement?

In other words, given a continuous random vector $(X, Y)$,

can we find some function $T: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow [0, 1]^2$ such that $T(X, Y)$ is uniformly distributed over $[0, 1]^2$?

Thank you.

Comment: I think you can, but it's maybe not what you're looking for: we can still consider the uniformly distributed variable $F_X(X)$. From it, we can extract two IID uniform variables by taking the odd and even binary digits, giving a uniformly distributed vector on $[0, 1]^2$. The more obvious approach of considering $(F_X(X), F_Y(Y))$ doesn't work, eg because of the example $(X, X)$ where $X$ is uniform on $[0, 1]$. Also, $F_{X,Y}(X, Y)$ doesn't have to be uniform on $[0, 1]$, eg consider $(X, Y)$ IID uniform on $[0, 1]$.